# Customize URL of a R bookdown site

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown

I have written a textbook using `bookdown` and published it to `bookdown.org/connect` via RStudio.  The URL is currently of the format

`https://bookdown.org/connect/#/apps/x0x0x0x0z1z2z3z4etcetc/`  [not the actual link!]

I believe there is a way to customize this URL to be e.g. `bookdown.org/mybook`.  I have looked up some help guides that you can edit this by going to your access site, and clicking on the ContentURL box. When I do that it highlights the URL, but I am not able to edit it in any way - just copy it.

[image]

Is there an easy way to customize the URL?

Comment: I don't see any documentation for creating custom URL names. Not sure bookdown.org wants to be in the business of deciding who gets which name. Might be better to ask at https://community.rstudio.com/ though.

Comment: it seems like it is doable - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/227014148-Custom-application-URLs-in-RStudio-Connect  - but perhaps I'm reading this wrongly.  I did make a post to the community forum yesterday morning but didn't receive any replies, so thought I'd try here.

Comment: Yeah, that support document makes sense if you are running your own instance of RStduio Connect. But because bookdown.org is managed by RStudio, I doubt they give the same access to every one to choose vanity URLs on their free hosing service. What if multiple people wanted the same URL? But that's just my understand. I can't back that up with any official docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bookdown`'s `publish_book` function to add the name of your book, or the Publish to Server button in RStudio allows for a Title input field where you can also add the name of your book that will be a part of the vanity URL. Your RStudio Connect profile name should go before the name of your book, so the format would be bookdown.org/RStudio Connect profile name/name of your book/